Combining Path Optimizer with Send Time Optimization
Current situation: We do a 50-50 split along with STO for AB testing. This means if we have an audience of 50k, 25k would get the winning email, and 25k would get the poor-performing email. This seems like a big risk.
New approach: I've recommended we start using Path Optimizer with Send Time Optimizer.
Concern: If we use STO with Path Optimizer and have a holdback group, how would it decide the winner after 24 hours? Because someone would get an email at 10 am and some would get it 11pm, how does it then decide the winner?
Does anyone have any advice on how to best use Path Optimizer? Maybe I should just go for Manual Selection?


